# How to get last and first values from attribute in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to get the first and last values from an attribute value,

(ie):

```
<entry aid:table="cell" aid:ccols="1" aid:theader="" aid5:cellstyle="chart_cellformat_headline" rowsep="1" colsep="1" align="center" spanname="col234"><para><emphasis aid:cstyle="bold" role="bold">Habla real</emphasis></para></entry>
```

from the above tag I want to get the values `2` and `4` from `spanname="col234"` attribute, I didnt tried any, Im new to XSLT

Please anybody share any ideas

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want exactly the first and last values from any digits

Assuming you actually want the fourth and the last character of a string, try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(@spanname, 4, 1)"/>
```

for the former, and:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(@spanname, string-length(@spanname), 1)"/>
```

for the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the obvious answer is to simply use the `substring` function:

```
substring(@spanname, 4, 1)
substring(@spanname, 6, 1)
```

but of course this depends on the format of every instance of this field being identical. What happens if values could be more than 10?

Comment: Thank for your swift reply, this will work if spanname="col23456" ? I want exactly the first and last values from any digits

Comment: Thank you so much for your help on the time, your answer is really very helpful